# Field not being injected with Dagger

Tags: android, dagger-2

In the following code, the field serviceUtil is not being injected by Dagger:

AppController.kt

```
class App : Application() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var serviceUtil: ServiceUtil

    init {
        DaggerAppComponent
            .builder()
            .build()
            .inject(this)
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        context = this
    }

    fun startService() {
        serviceUtil.startService()
    }

    companion object {
        lateinit var context: App
    }
}
```

AppComponent.kt

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [(ServiceUtilModule::class)])
interface AppComponent {
    fun inject(app: Application)
}
```

ServiceUtilModule.kt

```
@Module
class ServiceUtilModule {
    @Provides
    fun provideServiceUtil() : ServiceUtil {
        return ServiceUtil()
    }
}
```

From my main activity I call:

```
App.context.startService()
```

Comment: Do you have stacktrace? I think you mistyped here: fun inject(app: Application) 'App' not 'Application'

Comment: Woah! Thans a lot. Was busting my brains out over this for a few hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mistyped here

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [(ServiceUtilModule::class)])
interface AppComponent {
    fun inject(app: Application)
}
```

You should pass you App class as argument, not the basic one.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [(ServiceUtilModule::class)])
interface AppComponent {
    fun inject(app: App)
}
```